# Create a mobile app for my woocommerce website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am new to WooCommerce API... I have a Woocommerce website. Now I need to make an android mobile app. I have successfully completed the user registration and login. But now I want to create order, checkout, and payment for registered users. But I am not able to run the WooCommerce API.

For example, if I use this URL:

http://localhost/sitename/wp-json/wc/v3/orders

This problem occurs:

> "code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot
>   list resources.","data":{"status":401}}

How can I solve this and complete the order system for android from WooCommerce?

Please help. Please describe the process from 1st to last

Comment: I'd try finding the user-agent of your calls from a web-browser such as Chrome, then calling them from the mobile application and making sure that you change them to the browser's. The API is most likely specifically targeting certain user-agents to stop flooding.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem while using Woocommerce API. I used this code.

```
require "woocommerce_api"; //include api file

woocommerce = WooCommerce::API.new(
  "your_domain_name_with_http",
  "consumer_key",
  "consumer_secret",
  {
    wp_json: true,
    version: "wc/v1",
    query_string_auth: true
  }
)
```